# Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart - systemd service restarts every10 seconds, not intended

Tags: docker, service, redhat, systemd

System:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa)

I have created a systemd service:
# systemd service definition file
[Unit]
Description=RTDE UR Plugin
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

```
[Service]
# "-" path prefix makes systemd record the exit code,
# but the unit is not set to failed.
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=100
StandardOutput=journal+console
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm -dit  -e ROBOT_IP="172.17.0.2" --name rtdeplugin       rtdeplugin:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop rtdeplugin
Environment=CI=true

# Output to syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=rtdeplugin

User=root
Group=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run it (systemctl start rtdeplugin) it restarts every 10 seconds:

```
    Mar 07 11:39:19 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: Started RTDE UR Plugin.
    Mar 07 11:39:19 uslllx0057 rtdeplugin[1121463]: 060ede6757d3c53607080694ce52e5bbe79c596b4eb2c20f2a11fd333710c673
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 rtdeplugin[1121563]: rtdeplugin
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Succeeded.
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: Stopped RTDE UR Plugin.
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: Started RTDE UR Plugin.
    Mar 07 11:39:29 uslllx0057 rtdeplugin[1121762]: 7a0d7a9b0995a58ddbe32fe74e1a17e5a8a9824850ec32dbdd85ced2edaae000
    Mar 07 11:39:40 uslllx0057 rtdeplugin[1121861]: rtdeplugin
    Mar 07 11:39:40 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Succeeded.
    Mar 07 11:39:40 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
    Mar 07 11:39:40 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: rtdeplugin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
    Mar 07 11:39:40 uslllx0057 systemd[1]: Stopped RTDE UR Plugin.
```

When I run the same command from command line (docker run --rm -dit  -e ROBOT_IP="172.17.0.2" --name rtdeplugin rtdeplugin:latest) everything is running great - no restarts.

Any idea what could be the issues ?